# How do you save your games to the ChessMaster XI Database?

Tags: chessmaster

I recently started my chess career, and I am also an avid gamer. I thought ChessMaster XI would be great to get due to the massive amount of learning materials in it. Since it IS a game, I thought I'd ask the question here. How do you save your games to the Chessmater xi database? I am aware you can make your own database files, but I don't know how to save to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. When you actually play a game, you can click `File > Load`. Save the Game as a PGN file. Then head over to `Learn > Databases`. Create your own Database through the `File` menu. Then `File > Open > Your Database`.  To finish off, Click `File > Import Games > Your PGN File.`  Annotations don't seem to be kept, but again, for all the 780k games in the database, a small handful is annotated.